# How can I get an Image and then Use it to make an ImageIcon in Java GUI

Tags: java, arrays, image, user-interface

I am trying to make a card game and Am running into an issue with my getImage() function.
I have an String Array of the Cards ex:

```
private static String[] hearts = {"ah.gif","2h.gif","3h.gif","4h.gif","5h.gif","6h.gif","7h.gif","8h.gif","9h.gif","th.gif","jh.gif","qh.gif","kh.gif"};
```

My getImage() looks like this:

```
public String getImage(Card card){

    if (0 == suit){
        img = hearts[rank];
    }
    else if (1 == suit){
        img = spades[rank];
    }
    else if (2 == suit){
        img = diamond[rank];
    }
    else if (3 == suit){
        img = clubs[rank];
    }
```

However, because it is stored as a string, I get an error when I try to use the img as an ImgIcon Ex:

```
    ImageIcon image = (card.getImage(card));
    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of ImageIcons and use the String array and a for loop to create the Icon array. Simple. :)

```
// in declaration section  
private ImageIcon heartsIcons = new ImageIcon[hearts.length];  

  // in code section
  try {
     for (int i = 0; i < hearts.length; i++) {
        // you may need different code to get the Image file vs. resource.
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(hearts[i]));
        heartsIcons[i] = new ImageIcon(img);
     }
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Could you post an example? I tried to create an array of ImageIcons but got a bunch of errors I had never seen before?

Comment: @DanielCampbell: e.g. above. You may wish to post your code and your error messages to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I posted the 2 errors that cam up. If you need any code I will post it. My guess is I am missing an Import File but I am not sure

Comment: @Daniel: What errors? I don't see any full error messages. And yes, post the code.

Comment: Figured It out, Thanks A bunch.

Comment: @DanielCampbell: congrats and you're welcome! Best of luck with your project!